# Software for planning a Ultra Marathon for Windows?

Tags: running, training, long-distance-running, coaching

I found a software called UltraRunner 3 for Mac, I wonder if exists something like, but for windows.
I would like to know if exists a software that given a gps route then could generate a plan for running all the route, I mean the software would split the route in small parts, then if there ir positive elevation then would say you haceto run at 10 mim/km.
Then the software would allow you to change the intensity of all the parts of the route, thas exist something like for windows?

Answer (score 1):

Hmm... well this sounds like a bad idea.

When you're running an ultra you need to listen to your body and know when to push it, how to feed it and how to water it. I wouldn't want to try and split a route down and plan it to that degree. You don't know what the terrain is like nor do you know if it's going to be hot or cold on the day.

Comment: Ultra Marathons like Badwater needs a lot of planification.. you already know that it will be very, very hot on the day.